# ufw and iptables on buster

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

I've got a RPi4 and I'm trying to configure ufw. The problem is that I get this error

> ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version

The versions of iptables and ufw are

```
iptables 1.8.2-4
libnftables0:armhf 0.9.0-2
libnftnl11:armhf 1.1.2-2
nftables 0.9.0-2
ufw 0.36-1
```

Linux version is `Linux rP15 4.19.50-v7l+`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution. Buster comes with two iptables flavours

```
 > $ update-alternatives --list iptables
   /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
   /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
```

By default it uses iptables-nft. When changes to iptables-legacy

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

it works with UFW without problems **after reboot**.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem immediately after installing `ufw`:

```
$ sudo ufw status
ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version
```

But after `reboot`ing (without changing any other settings) it started working (as suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120322/ufw-error-couldnt-determine-iptables-version)):

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

$ update-alternatives --display iptables | grep currently
  link currently points to /usr/sbin/iptables-nft

$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.11+ #1399 Thu Jan 28 12:02:28 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

$ dpkg -s ufw | grep Version
Version: 0.36-1
$ dpkg -s iptables | grep Version
Version: 1.8.2-4
```

I'm not sure, but I think [this Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=921680) is related.  If so, it's supposed to be fixed in Debian's `ufw` package's 0.36-3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Buster uses nftables.

I haven’t tried this, but it is supposed to support iftables commands.

It is possible to revert, but you may be better to look for an updated tutorial